# Cocoa [self invalidateShadow] doesn't work on a frame moving left, but does when moving right?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nswindow

I have a function inside my window class that moves its frame around when the scrollwheel is moved

```
-(void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)theEvent{
    switch (theEvent.phase) {

        // Whilst Scrolling
        case NSEventPhaseChanged:
            float newPos = [theEvent.window.contentView frame].origin.x + [theEvent scrollingDeltaX];
            [theEvent.window.contentView setFrame: NSMakeRect(newPos, 0, 600, 600];
            [self invalidateShadow];
            [self display];
            break;
    }
}
```

This has the desired effect, the frame moves left and right perfectly. There are two pieces of unintended behaviour that I can't seem to pin down.

1. The window is set to [window setHasShadow:YES], I want the window to be transparent so I initially set the window to

   [window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:0.75 alpha:0.00]];

but when this was the case, the gesture on the parts of the screen with no frame didn't register- once i turned the alpha up to

```
[window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:0.75 alpha:0.05]];
```

it did receive input. However, with either of these options selected the setHasShadow defaulted to bordering the frame rather than the actual window - is this intended behaviour?

1. Although the border is redrawn with the frame when it moves left, it does not follow it when it moves to the right!? What on earth could be different with + vs - scrollingDeltaX?

Hopefully somebody could provide some insight.

Comment: Were you able to figure it out?

Comment: Three years ago! I'm afraid that problem looks entirely alien to me.